# How to delete a branch which is already deleted from remote

Tags: git, git-branch

I work on a project with others developers, with a Github repo. We made a branch, then after the work with it has finished, we deleted the branch on Github. But on my local repo, I have again the branch (I see it on calling `git branch --list -a`). It was a remote branch, but it doesn't exist anymore on the remote repo.

I tried with `git branch -d remotes/origin/<branch>` (also with -D but that is not the problem). Git answered "error: branche 'remotes/origin/morgan-save-A' non trouvee" .

How could I delete it, if someone has an idea ? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: To delete a remote-tracking name with `git branch`, you must include the `-r` option. Using `--prune` (or `-p`) with `git fetch`, or running `git remote prune`, is easier. Consider also or instead setting `fetch.prune` to `true`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-branch%5D+delete+remote

Comment: Thanks @torek and @KaspiR, I cannot vote for comments (due to my reputation, I think). `git fetch --prune origin` made the expected operation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `git fetch --prune`

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune):

> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they
> are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a
> --tags option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for
> example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then they
> are also subject to pruning. Supplying --prune-tags is a shorthand for
> providing the tag refspec.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that will be helpful, but Git says `git fetch --prune remotes/origin/<branch> fatal: 'remotes/origin/<branch>' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Impossible de lire le dépot distant.  Veuillez vérifier que vous avez les droits d'acces et que le dépot existe.` Perhaps I have to delete the reference (tracking) to the remote deleted repo ?

Comment: You don't have to provide a branch name, it prunes all remote branches. e.g. `git fetch --prune origin` should do the trick for you